# How to implement logic gates in in C++

Tags: c++11, embedded

I am a self taught in C++ and I have been developing a control software in 
this programming language. My design contains among others also a C++
class which models AND gate with two inputs. At some point I have found that it would be fine to have AND gates with more than two inputs (eight inputs in maximum). My question is how to achieve this in the best 
way in C++?

I have been thinking about class templates. Is it good idea or is it better to use composition i.e. AND_03 consists of two AND_02 gates?

```
class AND_02 : public Logic_FB{

private:

public:
void AND_02(uint32_t result, uint32_t input_01, uint32_t input_02);
void update(void);

}
```

where

```
class Logic_FB{
    virtual void update(void) = 0;
}
```

is unified interface for other logic elements like OR gate, RS flip-flop and so on.

Comment: You want to have a different classes based on the number of inputs? Why not one class with a non-type variadic function template that can take any number of inputs?

Comment: P.W. thank you for your reaction. Yes, I want to have a different classs based on the number of inputs. I like your idea with variadic function template but I don't know how to pass addresses of logic inputs into class using this construction. In the design above I used class constructor for this. Do you mean that I should define the virtual method update as variadic function template?

Comment: Maybe something like: `template<int N> class AND...`? (N = number of inputs)

Comment: @Antonio thank you very much for your reaction. I need to somehow pass addresses of the processed inputs into the class. Please can you tell me how does this work for the solution you have suggested?

Comment: @L3sek A very easy way to implement may be: `template<int N> class AND {std::array<uint32_t, N> input_; uint32_t result_; public: AND(const std::array<uint32_t, N>& input, uint32_t result):input_{input}, result_{result}{}` or something like that.

Comment: Make the whole class variable and have the constructor take the number of input pins and an array of inputs as parameter. Ideally you might want to make some manner of "Pin" class that is a glorified bi-directional pointer, so that you can link different gates together. If you don't want to go that advanced, use bool not int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to create a class that has 8 inputs with defaults; setting the optional inputs to `true` for AND and `false` for OR will cause the unused inputs to have no effect on the result.

For example:

```
class AND
{
    public:
        AND( bool x0 = false, bool x1 = false, // Required inputs
             bool x2 = true, bool x3 = true,   // Optional inputs
             bool x4 = true, bool x5 = true,
             bool x6 = true, bool x7 = true )
    {
        input( x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x7, x7 ) ;
    }

    bool output()
    {
        return m_x0 && m_x1 && m_x2 && m_x3 &&
               m_x4 && m_x5 && m_x6 && m_x5 ;
    }

    bool input( bool x0, bool x1,                // Required inputs
                bool x2 = true, bool x3 = true,  // Optional inputs
                bool x4 = true, bool x5 = true,
                bool x6 = true, bool x7 = true )
    {
        m_x0 = x0 ;
        m_x1 = x1 ;
        m_x2 = x2 ;
        m_x3 = x3 ;
        m_x4 = x4 ;
        m_x5 = x5 ;
        m_x6 = x6 ;
        m_x7 = x7 ;
        return output() ;
    } 

    private:
        bool m_x0, m_x1, m_x2, m_x3,
             m_x4, m_x5, m_x6, m_x7 ;
} ;
```

Usage examples:

```
AND z;
bool out = z.input( a, b, c ) ;             // three input gate
```

---

```
AND z;
bool out = z.input( a, b, c, e, f, g ) ;    // six input gate
```

---

```
AND z( a,b,c,d ) ;        // Four inputs
bool out = x.output() ;
```

Comment: Clifford, thank you for your idea. I like it. What I have been thinking about is how to extend this idea for my situation. I haven't been using bools instead of I have a variable of type uint32_t in bits array role. The logic gates work above this bits array.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to use default parameters

```
class AND_02
{
public:
    AND_02(bool x0, bool x1, bool x2 = true, bool x3 = true)
        : x0{x0}, x1{x1}, x2{x2}, x3{x3}
    {
    }

    bool result()
    {
        return x0 && x1 && x2 && x3;
    }

private:
    bool x0{false};
    bool x1{false};
    bool x2{false};
    bool x3{false};

    void update(void)
    {
        //do something
    }
};
```

and you can use it like

```
    AND_02 andGateXY(false, true);
    AND_02 andGateXY2(true, true);
    std::cout << "Result: " << andGateXY.result();
    std::cout << "Result2: " << andGateXY2.result();
    if(andGateXY.result() && andGateXY2.result())
    {

    }
    std::cout << "Result2: " << (andGateXY.result() && andGateXY2.result());
```

Comment: You should probably rename the class `AND` - the `_02` suffix in the original is presumably to reflect the fact that it tool just two inputs.  You example usage does not illustrate the use of three or four inputs, and the question asked for up to 8 inputs so you might have extended it to support that.  Otherwise the solution  is sound.